# Need to run a protected method when my class is instantiated

Tags: c#

I have a base class with some Custom Attributes, this class is the base class for many other clases 
This is my class:

```
[CustomAttribute1("First")]
[CustomAttribute2("Other")]
public class Foo
{
    protected void checkAttributes()
    {
        // Need to run this code when the class and derived classes are instantiated 
    }
}
```

Then if I créate an instance

```
Foo MyClass = new Foo();
```

or build a dereived class:

```
[CustomAttribute1("FirstDerived")]
public CustClass : Foo
{
    public CustClass(int MyVar)
    {
        //Something here
    }
    public void OtherMethod()
    {
    }
}

CustClass MyClass = new CustClass(5);
```

I need the method **checkAttributes()** allways run.

IS that Posible?

There is another aproach ?

NOTE: I need to be shure **checkAttributes()** runs even if in derived classes the constructor is redefined:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just define a constructor that calls this method:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        checkAttributes();
    }

    protected void checkAttributes()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

As long as every constructor on `Foo` winds up calling `checkAttributes()` (either directly or by chaining to a constructor that does) derived classes will not be able to avoid the check.

(It's unclear why this method would be protected, though.  Consider making it private, as it sounds like it is a one-time check run when an object is constructed, and shouldn't need to be run later.)

---

One of `Foo`'s constructors **must** be called (directly or indirectly) by any type that derives from `Foo` (directly or indirectly).

From section 10.11.1 of the C# 5 language specification:

> All instance constructors (except those for class `object`) implicitly include an invocation of another instance constructor immediately before the *constructor-body*.
>
> ...
>
> If an instance constructor has no constructor initializer, a constructor initializer of the form `base()` is implicitly provided.

The *only* way that a derived type can avoid calling a constructor on `Foo` would be to infinitely recurse into one of its own constructors, which would eventually lead to a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: But if in derived class there is another constructor like Foo(int myvar) what happen ?

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez Constructors on any type **must** call exactly one other constructor (`System.Object` being the only exception), either on the same type or on a parent type.  If a chained constructor call is omitted, the parent no-arg constructor is used.  (If the parent type does not contain a no-arg constructor and no chained constructor is explicitly specified in a derived type's constructor, it is a compile-time error.)  [See a demo.](http://ideone.com/OgXXeA)

Comment: It mean the empty constructor allways run on my type and derived types? My problem is on derived classes , they could implement it's owns constructors.

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez Yes. I just answered that question. **Every constructor must call exactly one other constructor**, on the same type or on a parent type. Constructors on types derived from `Foo` have **no choice** but to call a `Foo` constructor (directly or through another constructor on the same type).  If you don't believe me then try to circumvent this restriction yourself.

Comment: It mean if Foo() is never used, checkAttributes never happen ? There is another workaround ? sorry I believe you, just don't have much experience. Just I'm stoped at this point for 2 days.

Comment: If `Foo()` is the only constructor that `Foo` defines, then **it must be called by a derived type**. "If `Foo()` is never used" is a meaningless question since **`Foo()` must be used**. I have updated my answer to address this point.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34180/discussion-between-juan-pablo-gomez-and-cdhowie)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it on each object creation of the object you will have to call it in a normal constructor .

```
  public Foo()
  {
     //Your normal method call
  }
```

However if you want it to run only once during your application lifetime you can call in a static constructor Like

```
static Foo()
{
    // your static method that needs to be run only once
}
```

Comment: Tks a lot. but I need to run for each object.